# Can not save embedded form in symfony 1.4.8 with SQL Server, Propel15

Tags: sql-server, symfony1, propel

I have a 1:M relationship of Events with Event Dates. In the EventForm class, I am embedding the EventDate forms as so:

```
$this->embedRelation('EventDate', array('title' => 'dates', 'empty_label' => 'New'));
```

and filling the initial data on the edit forms as so:

```
  public function updateDefaultsFromObject()
  {
    parent::updateDefaultsFromObject();

      $i = 1;
      $values = array();
      foreach ($this->object->getEventDates() as $obj)
      {
        $values[$i] = array(
                    'EventID' => $this->object->getPrimaryKey(),
                    'EventDateID' => $obj->getEventDateId(),
                    'startDateTime' => $obj->getStartDateTime(),
                    'endDateTime' => $obj->getEndDateTime());
        $i++;
      }

    $this->setDefault('dates', $values);
  }
```

The problem is when it tries to save I get:

```
Unable to execute UPDATE statement [UPDATE EventDates SET EVENTDATEID=:p1
WHERE EventDates.EVENTDATEID IS NULL ] [wrapped: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General 
error: 8102 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server 
[8102] (severity 16) [(null)]]
```

MSSql error 8102 is that it is trying to update an identity column, which is EVENTDATEID. I have no idea why it's doing this. Also, it I have a feeling, judging by the update statement, that there is an empty object in $this->object->getEventDates() that it is trying to update. If I could fix that somehow, I assume (see: pray) that it will fix this error.

Comment: sfFormDoctrine::updateDefaultsFromObject() takes care about embedded forms (not sure about Propel). Why do override it?

Comment: I had an issue where the embedded date forms were not being populated with the event's current date data. Implementing the overridden method as above fixed it. Just now, it's not saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, finally. The array keys for setting the values in this block

public function updateDefaultsFromObject()
  {
    parent::updateDefaultsFromObject();

```
  $i = 1;
  $values = array();
  foreach ($this->object->getEventDates() as $obj)
  {
    $values[$i] = array(
                'EventID' => $this->object->getPrimaryKey(),
                'EventDateID' => $obj->getEventDateId(),
                'startDateTime' => $obj->getStartDateTime(),
                'endDateTime' => $obj->getEndDateTime());
    $i++;
  }

$this->setDefault('dates', $values);
```

Were wrong. They are supposed to use the actual column names and not the PHP names of the variables. So I had to change

```
'EventID' => $this->object->getPrimaryKey(),
'EventDateID' => $obj->getEventDateId(),
```

to

```
'eventID' => $this->object->getPrimaryKey(),
'eventdateID' => $obj->getEventDateId(),
```